# How Can I create an iPod playlist for someone else? (without itunes)

Tags: ipod, playlists

My girlfriend is leaving for college this weekend, and I thought I'd make her a playlist (because really, who uses CDs anymore?).

I consider myself quite computer savvy, but I have almost zero experience with an ipod.

Is there a simple way to create a playlist for her ipod? (I'll probably load it via iTunes on her PC, but I want to make the playlist on mine, and then copy it over via a flash drive).

So I believe will need to copy the MP3s, and the "playlist file" over.

How can I create the playlist file without using itunes?

Comment: What multimedia player do you use?

Comment: songbird, vlc, and amarok. (on this particular pc I use songbird and vlc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method, if you don't want to use any software, would be to gather your "playlist" into a folder with your MP3s. You should be able to create a new playlist in iTunes, select all your songs, then drag-and-drop them into the playlist. They'll automatically be added to the iTunes library as well as the playlist.

Comment: so if I just create a folder of the MP3s I can then drop them into a playlist on her itunes?

Comment: Yup. Drag + Drop is usually the easiest method for adding songs to iTunes anyways (or at least the method I use) and works for multiple files so it should work fine.